# D3 Cannot read property 'alphaTarget' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, undefined

I try to use the D3 Library in Angular 8. My problem is that I try to make my nodes draggable but I have a "Cannot read property 'alphaTarget' of undefined" error and I can't find the error in my code.

The error occurs in this snippet "graph.simulation.alphaTarget(0.1).restart();" but I don't know why. What's wrong here?

Can anybody pls help me?

d3.service.ts

```
  applyDraggableBehaviour(element, node: Node, graph: ForceDirectedGraph) {
const d3element = d3.select(element);



function started(event) {
  /** Preventing propagation of dragstart to parent elements */
  event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();


  if (!event.active) {
    graph.simulation.alphaTarget(0.1).restart();
  }

  event.fx = event.x;
  event.fy = event.y;

  event.on('drag', dragged).on('end', ended);

  function dragged() {
    
    node.fx = event.x;
    node.fy = event.y;
  }

  function ended() {
    if (!event.active) {
      graph.simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    }
    node.fx = null;
    node.fy = null;
  }
}

d3element.call(d3.drag()
.on('start', started));
```

}

Comment: console.log(graph) at the beginning of your function and you will see that simulation does not exist inside

Comment: Yes you're right. "public simulation: d3.Simulation<any, any>;"  This is the simulation of ForceDirectedGraph. But I still don't know whats the problem here

Comment: do you know what to do now?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: @Daniel If `graph` is your simulation, as you have said, then don't you just want `graph.alphaTarget(0.1)`?

Comment: alphaTarget exists only in simulation. I need to declare it like graph.simulation.alphaTargen(0.1).restart()

Comment: It shows me undefined when i put console.log(graph.simulation)